# Link error- missing required architecture i386 in file-symbols not found

Tags: c, linker, ld, i386, armv6

I am working on an app that uses a twitter API.

The app runs fine when it is hooked up to an IOS device, but when I change the architecture from armv6 to i386 to get it running on the simulator I get this error:

```
  ld: warning: ignoring file       /Users/username/Desktop/tweetsAloud/tweets2/tweetsAloud/Src/NeoSpeech/lib-i iphoneos/libvt_eng_julie.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_VT_LOADTTS_ENG", referenced from:
      -[TweetsViewController viewWillAppear:] in TweetsViewController.o
  "_VT_UNLOADTTS_ENG", referenced from:
      -[TweetsViewController viewWillDisappear:] in TweetsViewController.o
  "_VT_TextToFile_ENG", referenced from:
      -[TweetsViewController readyStringToPlay:] in TweetsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I have read up a lot of suggestions already and tried most of them with little luck.

I first made sure I had all my frameworks, then I tried editing the project.pbxproj, still did not work.

I have tried cleaning and changing the build settings.

Anyone have any ideas why I get this error message?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably linking your i386 project against an arm build of library NeoSpeech/lib-i iphoneos/libvt_eng_julie.a. That is what the warning means.

If you have an i386 version if this lib, then change your linker settings to point to that version instead. If you don't have the i386 version of this lib, then you'll have to get it from the author, or compile it yourself if you have the source code.

Good luck.

Comment: And how do you compile an i386 version of the source code? What settings do I need to do in XCode? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have the source code and XCode project for this library? If yes, then you need to build the simulator target. If you obtained this library from some place, then you can probably obtain the i386 version in the same place.